# Trying to run Windows 10 OS on Nvme but can't last long before the drive freezes up

Tags: ssd, enclosures

I have successfully installed windows 10 64-bit on a Smasung 970 Pro Nvme SSD inside a MyDigitalSSD Nvme enclosure. I am hooked up to a surface book 2. l and am running the OS in the SSD.

I've run Windows through the paces just fine, but at seemingly random times, when I restart, it freezes on the boot screen when the loading circle is spinning. I have not found a way to fix it, until I start from scratch with WintoUSB and re-load Windows again. I've tried this twice and the 1st time, it happened 30 min. In while restarting for Windows updates, and the 2nd install crashed maybe 6 hours in, while restarting for graphics drivers.

What am I doing wrong that causes the enclosure/ssd to freeze up?

Comment: This can be answered (and I will if it gets re-opened). The problem indicated is a well-known issue.

Comment: I am guessing I could be a connectivity issue with imperfect contact on a minute scale since it's over USB?

Comment: Very unlikely. That would cause frequent freezes and/or device reconnects. Which isn’t happening here.

Comment: Well @Tonny it's been reopened. What's the answer?

Comment: @music2myear I’m at work with very limited internet access. Will answer tonight.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known problem when using a USB drive as system disk. It is not specific to Nvme drives. It can also be seen using SATA and PATA external disks. The faster the system (computer and/or drive), the bigger the chance it will go wrong at some point.

USB was never designed to be used in this way. The main problem is that the USB bus can't guarantee sustained IO to any device.
At regular intervals the USB controller can (and will) briefly halt all data-traffic on the USB bus so it can do internal housekeeping to verify that all attached devices it knows about are still there and no others have shown up. This also happens when the USB controller gets reset (by hardware reset or software reset from the OS/driver).
If this happens at a critical moment (like reboot) you get a freeze and potentially data-corruption of the filesystem on the drive.

There are a lot of factors that influence the frequency with which it happens and when exactly it occcurs (any time, reboots, cold starts, all of the above).
Power-management, speed of the computer, USB controller, USB hubs (most motherboards have an internal hub between controller and the USB ports) and the USB to Disk converter chip in the external enclosure all have a part in this.

You can try a number of things to see if it improves the situation: (All these are aimed at changing the overall timing between drive and laptop in the hope of finding a sweet spot where the problem doesn't occur.)

- Make sure the laptop is in the "High Performance" power-management settings. Or if it already is, try the "Balanced" setting to see if that works better.
- Whether the laptop is on mains power or on battery may make a difference.
- If the external disk enclosure can be used with an external power-supply try that. (Or if that is not possible a powered USB hub between laptop and drive may help.)
- Windows 10 has the "Fast Startup" option. Try disabling that.
- Make sure "Write Caching" is disabled in Windows for this drive.

If all else fails there is the official Microsoft "Windows To Go" option buildin in Windows 8 and 10 which you can use to create a Windows on USB stick. This is different from a direct installation on a USB drive. Microsoft tweaks the USB2Go install so it uses safer ways of accessing the USB drive while running, which normally doesn't create these lockup problems at all. The drawback of this approach is that Win2Go is usually a bit slower, on the same hardware, as a direct install on a USB drive.

Comment: thank you very much for the information. It helped me find a solution.
First, what worked;
I was trying to use a mentioned older version of windows 10 2018 that could be installed free with WinToUSB... bad idea. It did not utilize Windows To Go.
Using the most recent from the source recognizes how it's being installed, as in that attempt, I got a notification saying it was Windows To Go, and telling me to not unplug while it's on, etc. 
Disabling Write Caching. I'm not sure how much it helped, as Windows to go forces the quick removal option, but I no longer have the crashing issue.

Comment: So it seems after the last update it locked up again in the same manner, and after starting over from scratch, installing Windows still cause the same crash 

Comment: I think it has something to do with the new Windows cumulative update that is now causing it to crash. Each time I start over, everything works fine, until I do all the updates. I can't be sure it is, since there are dozens of updates. Not sure how to proceed from here.

Comment: Here's the link to the update I think might be at fault. It is not always this one left in the list, however. https://photos.app.goo.gl/jcR8jajSgj7FKene6